# How to call a WebAPI from WinRT

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-runtime

I try to call a WebAPI from WinRT. In WinRT I wrote serializable classes, which I want to be sent to the WebAPI:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class RecognizeItem
{
    [DataMember()]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
}
```

Next step send data to server:

```
            RecognizeItem system = new RecognizeItem()
            {
                Id = login,
                Image = LoadImage
            };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(system);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json); 
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/RecognizeItem/", content);
```

In the implementation of the webAPI I have implemented a serializable class as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class RecognizeItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }

}
```

And my ApiController:

```
public string Post([FromBody] RecognizeItem image)...
```

But in response I see the following status:

> StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type'

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I think the BitmapImage within your custom type may be causing the issue. Have you tried to convert the Image property to a byte array before serializing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Content-Type is a header of the content, not of the request.

Try setting your content by passing the content-type to the StringContent constructor:

Replace

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
```

by

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(json,
                                Encoding.UTF8, 
                                "application/json");
```